# Polymer throwing error invalid regex on a valid regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, polymer, paper-elements

I'm using polymer paper input and using pattern for validating the input field.

My validation string is

```
 ^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

I checked it an valid expression [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/M1najb/1)

But, My polymer code throws error in console saying some escape problem.

```
 <paper-input label="Your name" pattern='^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$' required onfocusout="validate()" error-message="Please enter VALUE"></paper-input>
```

Error in console says

```
 Pattern attribute value ^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/: Invalid escape
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h932rkr8/22/). The error can be seen in console.

Comment: Seems like chrome doesn't process overly complicated regex in the same say as the regex validator, this looks very complicated, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Stu I'm actually re-witting a legacy code, but I'm not supposed to change expressions. although its just an email validation I'm aware of the alternatives but that doesn't help me because I cannot use those

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes this matching could be an issue I missed this point Actually those regex were defined on server side they were stored as string and then used somewhere in code. I just copied that regex to pattern attribute

Comment: No certainly not pardon my ignorance, I went away because console HTML also displayed escaping error

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have one more such expression (this is used to check Urls) /^(http(?:s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:\.|\-)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(?:\:\d+)?(?:\/[\w\-]+)*(?:\/?|\/\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$/ throwing same error Can you please help ?

Comment: The point is that you should not escape special symbols that do not have to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You must not escape `"`:

```html
<form>
  <input label="Your name" pattern='^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$' required error-message="Please enter VALUE">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

NB: I changed `paper-input` to `input` here to make the snippet work.

Comment: That helps :), So is that that in pattern expression we should not escape \\ and \" ?

Comment: @VinodLouis It seems `"` is the only character to unescape. I edited.

Comment: but then in this ^(http(?:s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:\.|\-)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(?:‌​\:\d+)?(?:\/[\w\-]+)‌​*(?:\/?|\/\w+\.[a-zA‌​-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[\w]+\=‌​[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]‌​+\=[\w\-]+)*)$ I don't have \" I'm confused now

Comment: This is another regex where `"` are not handled, you can't compare.

Comment: For urls, the pattern without unwanted escaped characters would be: `^(http(?:s)?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:\.|-)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(?::\d+)?(?:\/[\w-]+)*(?:\/?|\/\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[\w]+=[\w-]+)?)?(?:&[\w]+=[\w-]+)*)$`. eg. in that pattern, `\:` becomes `:`. But be careful when you copy/paste text, there are invisible special chars in the pattern from your coment.